# Vertical and horizontal center within responsive float

Tags: html, css

I have two halves side by side which is achieved using a float.

The height of the first half is defined by an image.

The second half has some copy which needs to be aligned vertically and horizontally.

Here's what [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) recommends from "Is the element of unknown width and height?":

```css
.half {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="half">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532517308734-0565178471d2" alt="Image from Unsplash">
</div>

<div class="half">
  
  <div class="parent">
 
    <div class="child">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div><!-- .child -->
    
  </div><!-- .parent -->

</div><!-- .half -->
```

This isn't working. Do both halves need an equal height and can this be achieved with JS or CSS?

Comment: float and vertical-align do not go along, use display to manage your layout. flex, grid or table and even inline-block for old browsers will do the job.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the height of the image in the left half influences the height of the right half.

Comment: @MrLister The image defines the height of the first half, not the second. Updated question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap both in a `.flexcontainer` (which makes all child elements in a row equal height), make sure `.parent` takes 100% height from `.half`.

```css
.half {
  /* removed float here */
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* new styles below */

.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.parent {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="half">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532517308734-0565178471d2" alt="Image from Unsplash">
  </div>

  <div class="half">

    <div class="parent">

      <div class="child">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
      <!-- .child -->

    </div>
    <!-- .parent -->

  </div>
  <!-- .half -->
</div>
<!-- .flexcontainer -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have trouble aligning material like that. The best solution I have been able to find so far is to set the top and left with calculations based on vh and vw. It is is a lot of math trying to figure out.
Flex and grid may not respond in some platforms from experience. So, if you need something very absolute with no overlapping elements then I believe table is your best option.